# Any way to make hibernate query return key-value map automatically (omit "as")?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, dictionary

Since data stored in Mysql always has a column name, I thought it will be great if there is a way to retrieve the records in a key-value map.

The Hibernate mechanism for join queries can't help too much, as we could only retrieve the `Object[]` result and deserialize the result ourself, or we could use [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select):

> This is most useful when used together with select new map:
>   `select new map( max(bodyWeight) as max, min(bodyWeight) as min, count(*) as n )
>   from Cat cat`

The query above gives a way of retrieving a map, but we have to define the key of the map(with `as`), I think it's just a case-by-case solution, it is not very elegant to hard-code the field name.

Isn't it better and generic that we find a way to automatically define the `key` of the retrieved map with just the column name? So can we  send a map with all the fields and let the application choose which field to use?

Answer (score 1):

Even if there was such a feature how could Hibernate decide which is the Map key and which columns from the Map value.

The most flexible solution is to define a DTO which will be used to hold the selected projection:

```
select new my.package.DTO(field1, field2, .., fieldn) from ...
```

And you simply pass the result to a [custom result transformer](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-multi-level-fetching/), which contains the exact result set key mapping logic.

Comment: Thanks for response, a DTO defination is a good idea, but still it should be modifed as the table column changes.

Comment: If we put the *compute* fields (such as count, max, min...) aside, we could use the column name a a key. And mostly, retrieving fields without the *computing* fields is mostly used, at least by our applications.

Comment: And if it's needed why not just name the ${column}_max or ${column}_min as a key? seems hibernate hasn't done that yet, but I think it will be a great helper if they add this feature.

Comment: If you change your column name you'd have to update your mapping and any native query anyway, and that's only an occasional event. The DTO can use an alias, so even if you change the column name, the alias will stay the same, so you won;t have to change the application logic.

Comment: You can open a ticket on Hibernate forum to request such a feature, but since there are already 2000 open tickets, you are better off implementing it yourself and submit a pull-request to the Hibernate core team.